# Multiple thread functions modifying the same list

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a file that contains over 27000 objects, I've made one function and run the same function 4 times, just giving the different chunks from the file.

```
def start_one():
    print("Starting thread 1")
    parse_data(json_data[0:6750], "file_1")


def start_two():
    print("Starting thread 2")
    parse_data(json_data[6750:13500], "file_2")


def start_three():
    print("Starting thread 3")
    parse_data(json_data[13500:20250], "file_3")


def start_four():
    print("Starting thread 4")
    parse_data(json_data[20250:27002], "file_4")
```

Now my `parse_data()` function has this:

```
no_dups = []
for obj in json_data:
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, proxies=PROXIES, headers=headers,
                                 data=test.format(genre_id=obj['id'], from_to_num=300))
        for item in response.json()['jsonGraph']['videos']:
            if item not in no_dups:
                no_dups.append(item)
```

And this is how my `json_data` file looks,

```
    {
        "id": "67614",
        "name": "Anime"
    },
    {
        "id": "2653",
        "name": "Anime Action"
    },
```

Basically, genres, now I'm going through each one of those genres and making requests, which returns some ID, however, 1 ID can have multiple genres, hence the same ID will be returned multiple times, and then making requests with those IDs, and you can imagine how much this is slowing my script. Is it possible to make `no_dups` list global or something? I tried something like this, but doesn't seem to work.

```
def thread1(lst):
    global check
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 and i not in check:
            check.append(i)
    print(check)


def start1():
    thread1([i for i in range(0, 10)])


def start2():
    thread1([i for i in range(5, 10)])


Thread(target=start1).start()
Thread(target=start2).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhh.. Apparently I can do this..

```
def thread1(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 and i not in check:
            check.append(i)
    print(check)


def start1():
    thread1([i for i in range(0, 10)])


def start2():
    thread1([i for i in range(5, 10)])

check = [] # Global scope..
Thread(target=start1).start()
Thread(target=start2).start()
```